# Unmarshal xhtml as string using xsd

Tags: xhtml, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal a large xhtml document using XSD's and jaxb. I've got everything working except for one part, which contains pure html. Here is an example of the xhtml I'm getting (I am able to grab every element except the "content"):

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text">...</title>
<id>...</id>
<updated>...</updated>
<entry>
    <id>...</id>
    <title type="text">...</title>
    <updated>...</updated>
    <author>
        <name>...</name>
    </author>
    <content type="xhtml"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div>{html...}<div>{html...}</div>/<div>/<div>
    </content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Here's an expansion of the xsd file:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ApCategoriesJAXB" >
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="updated" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="link" type="tns:ApLinkJAXB" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="entry" type="tns:ApEntryJAXB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ApEntryJAXB">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="updated" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="author" type="tns:ApAuthorJAXB" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>  
        <xsd:element name="link" type="tns:ApLinkJAXB" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="category" type="tns:ApCategoryJAXB" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>  
        <xsd:element name="content" type="tns:ApContentJAXB" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>            
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ApCategoryJAXB" >
    <xsd:sequence></xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="term" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="scheme" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ApContentJAXB" >
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="div" type="tns:ApDivJAXB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>    

<xsd:complexType name="ApDivJAXB" >
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I have tried every combination of nested xsd elements, complexTypes, xsd:any etc etc and cannot seem to get this "content" value no matter what I try. I am happy to take all the html as a string, or unmarshal it into an object.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts.

** I've edited the xsd part to include relevant parts. I've tried both nesting the "any" element in the "div" complexType as seen, as well as skipping the "div" complexType altogether.

Thanks again.

Comment: I should also note that this xhtml is coming from a 3rd party api and the content structure within the "content" tag is unknown, aside from that it is html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `<content>` to have a type of `xsd:string`, you need to encode or otherwise escape the HTML.  You could use CDATA sections, Base64 encoding, or escape all the entities (e.g. `<` to `&lt;`, etc.).

Otherwise, `xsd:any` should work.  Can you provide a more complete example of your XSD when you tried this?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your reply. I've expanded the xsd section in my original post to show my use of "any". This is just my most recent attempt in the same line of attempts. Can I use CDATA sections in the xsd? Or is that something that needs to be in the incoming xhtml? In which case I have no control over. Thanks again.

Comment: @ryan - The CDATA sections would need to be in the incoming XML/XHTML.

Comment: @zeisemer - Does it look as though I'm using the "any" tag correctly in the example above? I've tried it various ways to no avail as of yet.

Comment: @ryan - No, that's exactly your problem.  You're declaring `namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`, but that's the XML namespace of the root XML, not what you're expecting to be in that element.  You need `namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` - or just omit the namespace attribute all together.